# Understanding how to construct GHC.Generics Rep's and convert back to values

Tags: haskell, generics, ghc, ghc-generics

I'm trying to learn about how to use [`GHC.Generics`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html). A fascinating topic but daunting.

While reading through the blog entry [24 Days of GHC Extensions: DeriveGeneric](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-16-derive-generic.html), I learned how to take a value and navigate its `Rep`. Okay.

However, reading the blog entry [Building data constructors with GHC Generics](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-04-26-constructing-generically.html) which describes the analog of constructing the `Rep` and converting it back to a value, I got stumped. I've read through [a](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html) [number](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics) [of](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/generic-programming.html) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750867/how-to-construct-generic-functor-instances-using-ghc-generics-or-other-similar) [resources](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/23luc9/explain_like_im_not_a_phd_datatypeable_and/), but to no great help.

In the blog entry is the following code. First, constructing the `Rep`:

```
class Functor f => Mk rep f | rep -> f where
  mk :: f (rep a)

instance Mk (K1 i c) ((->) c) where
  mk = \x -> K1 x

instance (Mk l fl, Mk r fr) => Mk (l :*: r) (Compose fl fr) where
  mk = Compose (fmap (\l -> fmap (\r -> l :*: r) mk) mk)

instance (Mk f f') => Mk (M1 i c f) f' where
  mk = M1 <$> mk
```

Then, dealing with the `Compose`:

```
class Functor f => Apply f a b | f a -> b where
  apply :: f a -> b

instance Apply ((->) a) b (a -> b) where
  apply = id

instance (Apply g a b, Apply f b c) => Apply (Compose f g) a c where
  apply (Compose x) = apply (fmap apply x)
```

Then dealing with type ambiguity:

```
type family Returns (f :: *) :: * where
  Returns (a -> b) = Returns b
  Returns r = r

make :: forall b f z. (Generic (Returns b), Apply f (Returns b) b, Mk (Rep (Returns b)) f) => b
make = apply (fmap (to :: Rep (Returns b) z -> (Returns b)) (mk :: f (Rep (Returns b) z)))
```

Wow.

Really, I'm stuck at the very beginning, at the class `Mk` where `mk` returns a functor. My questions:

1. What is `mk` returning? Why is it a functor? What is the interpretation of its result? I can see that the `K1 i c` instance of `Mk` returns a function (I understand this is a functor) that takes a value and wraps it in `K1`, but `mk` for `Mk (l :*: r)` and `Mk (M1 i c f)` are completely lost on me.
2. I'm guessing `Compose` comes from `Data.Functor.Compose`, which means that when I do `fmap f x`, it does the `fmap` two levels deep into the composed functors. But I can't make sense of the nested `fmap`s inside the `Compose`.
3. For the instance of `M1 i c f`, I thought it would just wrap the inner values in `M1`, so the need to `M1 <$> mk` or `fmap M1 mk` makes no sense to me.

Obviously I'm not grokking the intent or meaning of these instances and how these instances interact to create the final `Rep`. I am hoping someone can enlighten me and provide a good explanation of how to use `GHC.Generics` along the way.

Comment: Note there are two seperate design "goals" (so to speak) at play here - generically deriving a function, and having that function be "nice". The author wanted to write a polyvariadic function, like `a -> b -> ... -> R` instead of having a chain of `Compose` which is what the `Mk` class generates: `Compose ((->) a) (Compose ((->) b) ... R`. If you are trying to understand generics, I think you can ignore everything other than the `Mk` class, which is the workhorse for generics here. I don't know why the author chose to write everything with Compose, then "convert" it to a polyvariadic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What is `mk` returning?

Let's go through a much simpler example In the documentation of GHC.Generics first. To achieve a generic function `encode :: Generic a => a -> [Bool]` that bit serialize every data type which has a Generic instance, they defined the type class below :

```
class Encode' rep where
  encode' :: rep p -> [Bool]
```

By defining `Encode'` instances for every Rep type (M1, K1, etc.), they made the function work universally on every data types.

In [Building data constructors with GHC Generics](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-04-26-constructing-generically.html), the author's final goal is a generic function `make :: Generic a => TypeOfConstructor a`, so naively one may define:

```
class Mk rep where
  mk :: (? -> p) -- what should '?' be?
```

And soon realize that it's impossible due to a few problems:

1. `->`, the function type in haskell only takes one argument at a time, so `mk` won't be able to return anything sensible if the constructor takes more than one argument.
2. The number and type of the arguments are unclear: it's relative to the `rep` type in concern.
3. It cannot be plain `p` as the result type. Without the `rep` context it's impossible to derive instances for `:*:` or `:+:`, and the function will no longer work on any nested data type.

Issue 1 can be solved with Data.Functor.Compose. A function of type `a -> b -> c` can be encoded into `Compose ((->) a) ((->) b) c`, it can be further composed while keeps a whole lot of information about argument types. And by making it a type parameter of `Mk`, issue 2 is solved too:

```
class Functor f => Mk rep f | rep -> f where
  mk :: f (rep p)
```

where `f` is generalization over `Compose f g` and `(->) a`, which contains type-level information to construct a `rep p`, i.e. everything before the final `->` in `a -> b -> c -> ... -> rep p`.

> 2. I'm guessing `Compose` comes from `Data.Functor.Compose`, which means that when I do `fmap f x`, it does the `fmap` two levels deep into the composed functors. But I can't make sense of the nested `fmap`s inside the `Compose`.

In the `Mk` instance of `:*:`:

```
instance (Mk l fl, Mk r fr) => Mk (l :*: r) (Compose fl fr) where
  mk = Compose (fmap (\l -> fmap (\r -> l :*: r) mk) mk)
```

`fmap` changes only the inner-most type of a nested Compose, in this case changes the final result of a n-ary function. `mk` here is literally concatenating two argument lists `fl` and `fr`, putting their results into a product type, namely

```
f :: Compose ((->) a) ((->) b) (f r)
g :: Compose ((->) c) ((->) d) (g r)
mk f g :: Compose (Compose ((->) a) ((->) b)) (Compose ((->) c) ((->) d)) ((:*:) f g r)

-- or unwrapped and simplified
(a -> b -> r) -> (c -> d -> r') -> a -> b -> c -> d -> (r, r')
```

> 3. For the instance of `M1 i c f`, I thought it would just wrap the inner values in `M1`, so the need to `M1 <$> mk` or `fmap M1 mk` makes no sense to me.

It does just wrap the inner values in `M1`, but it's unclear how long the argument list of the underlying `f` is. If it takes one argument then `mk` is a function, otherwise it's a Compose. `fmap` wraps the inner-most value of them both.