# How to create a Mk instance for GHC.Generics.U1?

Tags: haskell, generics, ghc-generics

I'm working through content at the blog posting [Building data constructors with GHC Generics](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-04-26-constructing-generically.html). My previous question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419297/understanding-how-to-construct-ghc-generics-reps-and-convert-back-to-values).

The posting has the following code to create a `Rep`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Functor.Compose

class Functor f => Mk rep f | rep -> f where
  mk :: f (rep a)

instance Mk (K1 i c) ((->) c) where
  mk = \x -> K1 x

instance (Mk l fl, Mk r fr) => Mk (l :*: r) (Compose fl fr) where
  mk = Compose (fmap (\l -> fmap (\r -> l :*: r) mk) mk)

instance (Mk f f') => Mk (M1 i c f) f' where
  mk = M1 <$> mk
```

Is it possible to create a similar instance for `U1`? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Since `U1` has no structure, you should be able to `mk` one out of thin air in `Identity`:

```
import Control.Monad.Identity

instance Mk U1 Identity where
    mk = pure U1
```