# Haskell generics. Constructing Rep

Tags: haskell

I got stuck on this tutorial https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-04-26-constructing-generically.html when trying verify the type of `mk` for `l :*: r` when `l = K1 _ a`, `fl = ((->) a)` and `r = K1 _ b`, `fr = ((->) b)`

```
class Functor f => Mk rep f | rep -> f where
  mk :: f (rep a)

instance Mk (K1 i c) ((->) c) where
  mk = \x -> K1 x

instance (Mk l fl, Mk r fr) => Mk (l :*: r) (Compose fl fr) where
  mk = Compose (fmap (\l -> fmap (\r -> l :*: r) mk) mk)
```

Now by the type class definition `mk :: f (rep _)` and we have `f = Compose ((->) a) ((->) b) = * -> a -> b -> *` and `rep _ = l:*:r` and so `mk :: a -> b -> l:*:r`. This is what I expected.

However, I think `(fmap (\l -> fmap (\r -> l :*: r) mk) mk) :: a -> b -> l:*:r` and I cant see how using this as a first argument to `Compose :: forall k k1. (k -> *) -> (k1 -> k) -> k1 -> *` will ever give back the expected signature of `mk`??

---

Also, I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35424427/11998382 helpful but I got lost at

```
f :: Compose ((->) a) ((->) b) (f r)
g :: Compose ((->) c) ((->) d) (g r)
mk f g :: Compose (Compose ((->) a) ((->) b)) (Compose ((->) c) ((->) d)) ((:*:) f g r)
```

Did they mean `fl :: Compose ((->) a) ((->) b) (f r)` or `mk f :: Compose ((->) a) ((->) b) (f r)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we have `f = Compose ((->) a) ((->) b) = * -> a -> b -> *` and `rep _ = l:*:r` and so `mk :: a -> b -> l:*:r`

You've got the spirit, but there's a few details I want to quibble on here.

First: `Compose ((->) a) ((->) b)` is not equal to anything interesting except itself. However, it is *isomorphic* to some other interesting types. For example, `Compose ((->) a) ((->) b) c` is isomorphic (but not equal!) to `a -> b -> c`. (I'm not sure what the `*`'s are in your equality or where they came from, though.)

Second: in this instance, `rep` (not `rep _`) is being replaced by `l :*: r`. Consequently, where you replaced `rep a` by `l :*: r`, you should actually be replacing `rep a` by `(l :*: r) a` (or, up to alpha renaming, `rep c` by `(l :*: r) c`). Like we did with `Compose`, we could observe an isomorphism here, namely that `(l :*: r) c` is isomorphic to `(l c, r c)`.

Putting these together, we have

```
f (rep a)
= { alpha renaming: a is not bound (but f and rep are) }
f (rep c)
= { definition of f and rep }
Compose ((->) a) ((->) b) ((l :*: r) c)
~= { the two isomorphisms described above }
a -> b -> (l c, r c)
```

> However, I think `(fmap (\l -> fmap (\r -> l :*: r) mk) mk) :: a -> b -> l:*:r` and I cant see how using this as a first argument to `Compose :: forall k k1. (k -> *) -> (k1 -> k) -> k1 -> *` will ever give back the expected signature of `mk`

Beware! There are *two* entities named `Compose`. One is at the type level, and has the kind you gave:

```
Compose :: forall k k1. (k -> *) -> (k1 -> k) -> k1 -> *
```

But there is another at the computation level, with a very different-looking type:

```
Compose :: f (g a) -> Compose f g a
```

In this type, the first `Compose` is the computation-level `Compose`, and the second `Compose` in is the type-level `Compose`.

It is the term-level `Compose` that is being used in the definition of `mk`, not the type-level one as you seem to be assuming. (In this part, you've also not been careful about the distinction between `l :*: r` and `(l :*: r) c`, as in the last bit.) So the correct version of the quoted statement is: `(fmap (\l -> fmap (\r -> l :*: r) mk) mk) :: a -> b -> (l:*:r) c`, so using this as the first argument to `Compose :: f (g a) -> Compose f g a` means that `Compose (fmap ... mk) :: Compose ((->) a) ((->) b) ((l:*:r) c)`.

Comment: Thanks! this has been valuable. I probably meant `Compose ((->) a) ((->) b) :: * -> a -> b -> *` rather than equals

Comment: @TomHuntington Okay. Well, if that's what you meant, it's still not quite right: `Compose ((->) a) ((->) b) :: * -> *`.

Answer (score 0):

So Compose is defined

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose {getCompose :: f (g a)}
```

The return type of `getCompose`

> Prelude Data.Functor.Compose> :t getCompose
>
> getCompose :: Compose f g a -> f (g a)

is of kind `*` and so determines the kind of Compose

> Prelude Data.Functor.Compose> :k Compose
>
> Compose :: (k -> *) -> (k1 -> k) -> k1 -> *

And the data constructor has type

> Prelude Data.Functor.Compose> :t Compose
>
> Compose :: f (g a) -> Compose f g a

So the purpose of Compose is just to encode types, it doesn't do anything with the term it stores.

I need to stop getting confused between type and data constructors, in Haskell you cant only tell the difference by the context.